How to Resolve 'Cannot modify header information' wordpress warning? Malicious script added to site. Cannot access wp admin
After encountering deprecated code notifications on my website's main section following a long absence from maintenance, I accessed my WordPress admin via the hosting site. Through a series of deactivating, reactivating, and updating plugins, I managed to remove the notifications and restore the site's appearance on desktop.
However, upon checking the site on mobile, I discovered that all links were redirecting to spam sites, indicating a hack. To address this, I updated my WordPress, hosting, and FTP passwords. Now, when attempting to access the WordPress admin, I encounter the following warnings:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/decorpai/public_html/wp-config.php:1) in /home3/decorpai/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1435 and 1438.
I've attempted to troubleshoot by examining the pluggable.php file in a code editor but am unsure of the issue's origin. Could this warning be related to the malicious redirects? Below is a screenshot of the code. I am relatively inexperienced in the back end side of wordpress, so I would greatly appreciate any help. Even just advise on how to resolve the redirects.


this line normally should redirect the page, but it doesn't because output already started, from a code in a previous loaded scripts. try inspecting the page source to see what is that output and where it came from.  please post text instead of images.

TAKE A FULL BACKUP! You have to delete all PHP files, including WordPress. Reinstall everything; WordPress, plugins, themes. Just restore the database. You may choose to get professional support.
